# How to get push notification with FCM in background on iOS (Swift4)

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4, ios11

How to get push notification in background? I have a problem in Swift4 iOS 11 with push notifications with FCM unable to retrieve notifications in the background only when the application is opened.

This is my coding:

AppDelegate.swift

```
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
        
        var window: UIWindow?
        static var DEVICE_ID = String()
        
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                    print(success)
                })
                
                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
                
            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }
            
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            
            return true
        }
        
        func connectToFcm() {
            Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
            
            if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
                AppDelegate.DEVICE_ID = token
                print("*********")
                print("Token Instance: \(token)")
                print("*********")
            }
        }
        
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            
            completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
            
        }
        
        func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
            connectToFcm()
        }
        
        func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
            
            guard let data: [String: Any] = remoteMessage.appData as? [String: Any] else {
                return
            }
            
            print(data)
            
         
        }
        
        func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            connectToFcm()
        }
        
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            
            
            completionHandler(.newData)
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

[Example: image send push notification with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIMHB.png)

Comment: Hey Just to confirm, you are not even getting the pop up for push notification  and It is in case application is in killed state or just in background

Comment: yes I did not get a notification when the application was killed and in the background. Is there my coding that is wrong or lacking. Please help

Comment: I did't get what the problem is in your code. But I have posted my steps below. Please cross verify with your steps.

Comment: I use the FCM method when the application is active and the notification appears successfully. When the application in my background uses the APN method and the notification does not appear and does not get notification data sent from the server. When I open the application again a notification appears.

Answer (score 2):

this source code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID

struct DataNotif: Codable {
    var title: String?
    var body: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case body
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "message_id"

    static var DEVICE_ID = String()
    var msg_body = ""
    var msg_title = ""

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func connectToFcm() {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            AppDelegate.DEVICE_ID = refreshedToken
            print("*********")
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
            print("*********")
        }else{
            print("Can't get token device")
        }

        connectToFcm()

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        print(userInfo)

        guard let data: [String: Any] = userInfo as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }

        let listData = data["notification"] as! String
        let jsonData = listData.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataJson = try decoder.decode(DataNotif.self, from: jsonData!)

            msg_body = dataJson.body!
            msg_title = dataJson.title!

            createNotification(title: msg_title, body: msg_body)

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }

        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    // messaging
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            AppDelegate.DEVICE_ID = token
            print("*********")
            print("Token Instance: \(token)")
            print("*********")
        }

        connectToFcm()
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {

        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")

        guard let data: [String: Any] = remoteMessage.appData as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }

        print(data)

        let listData = data["notification"] as! String
        let jsonData = listData.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataJson = try decoder.decode(DataNotif.self, from: jsonData!)

            msg_body = dataJson.body!
            msg_title = dataJson.title!

            createNotification(title: msg_title, body: msg_body)

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }

    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if let vc = window?.rootViewController as? HomeController {
            vc.scheduleNotification()
        }

        completionHandler(.newData)

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
        print("Disconnect FCM")
    }

    func createNotification(title: String, body: String) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: title, arguments: nil)
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: body, arguments: nil)
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.badge = NSNumber(integerLiteral: UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "pushNotif", content: content, trigger: nil)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase provides background and foreground support to Push Notifications. You can easily solve your problem by following steps:

**In your AppDelegate.swift import firebase library**

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
```

**Whenever app launch register for push notification service, add the following lines of code into your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        registerForPushNotifications(application: application)
        return true
    }
```

**Add extension methods of appDelegate to register for remote notification and to get device token from APNS**

```
       extension AppDelegate {
         func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
             if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
                    // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
                   Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
               } else {
                   let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        let savedAPNSToken = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedAPNSToken") as? String
        if savedAPNSToken != token {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "savedAPNSToken")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
}
```

**Use the following methods of notificationCenter to handle notification in the foreground and background states :**

```
// MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }


    /// Handle tap on the notification banner
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - center: Notification Center
    ///   - response: Notification response
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        completionHandler()
    }
```

**Firebase token renewel:**

```
// MARK: - MessagingDelegate
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
        let savedFCMToken = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedFCMToken") as? String
        if savedFCMToken != fcmToken {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: "savedFCMToken")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            // Update FCMToken to server by doing API call...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to find out the issue in your code but I am posting the steps how it should be done :-

1. Register for Push notifications

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   ```

   FirebaseApp.configure()
         self.registerForPushNotifications(application)
       return true
       }
           func registerForPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication){
               Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
               if #available(iOS 10, *) {

   ```
               let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
               center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                   // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
               }
               center.delegate=self
               application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
           }
           else{
               let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
               application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
               application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
           }
       }
   ```

2.Then handle your didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate :-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 

    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
            Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

        }
```

3. Handle your Firebase Messaging delegate :-

   extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
       func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

   ```
       let token = fcmToken
   // you can send your token to Server, from where you'll get the Push Notification


   }
   ```

   }

4.Then handle your UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate :-

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // this is called when application is Foreground and push arrives we show alert, sound, here.
                completionHandler([.alert, .sound])

            }
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void){
            let pushDictionary = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
         // handle your push here
        }
```

Comment: I did what you said step by step but still the same I did not get a notification in the background

Comment: Ok then go to your project. In target , select "Capabilities", then In "Background Modes", turn it on, and check "remote notifications" tab. And also enable "Push Notifications"

Comment: Please verify( "alert": "true",
        "badge": "true",
        "sound": "true") is true on server end

Comment: {
"priority": "high",
    "content_available": true,
    "alert": true,
    "badge": true,
    "sound": true,
"notification": {
    "title": "Notification Test",
    "body": "Body testing",
    "badge": "1"
    },
"registration_ids":
[
      "tokenId"
    ]
}

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes I meant this. Please share screenshot for your capabilities.

Comment: try to see the picture below

Comment: I've tried to do this "alert": true, "badge": true, "sound": true, it still doesn't work

Comment: Please help me Thanks you

Comment: I am so sorry I got back to you so late. The issue is not of server end. As the image you shared as I can see in the image you attached. Could you please share the image of your capabilities?