# How use Firebase Push notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried using Firebase Push notification in my app and somehow, the push notification doesn't work, I tried following several guides and nothing worked(and most were outdated). So I tried again and followed the firebase tutorial from googlepage. Still nothing works, can somebody please help me out here?

This is my my appDelegate

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase

var firebasetokenofuser = ""

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {




    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/171.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 133.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]


        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }


        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
            } else if let result = result {
                print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
                firebasetokenofuser = result.token
            }
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]

        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

- The bundle id is same in console and project
- APN key is used
- Key ID and TEAM ID are the same
- Added capability for Push Notifications
- Used production certificate
- Added Google plist file
- Added certificates to console

Still no push notification. Can somebody enlighten me on where I went wrong?

Edit

Edit : Its working now, the reason why it didn't work was because I thought I only needed production certificate and I didn't add a development certificate (fixed it with inputs from comments)

Comment: Did you embed GoogleServices-info.plist in your project and put push notification certificates in Firebase console for your app?

Comment: @MohyG Yes I did , am I missing anything else?

Comment: Try to upload APNs certificates in Firebase. Separate for development and production. Then try sending test message. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: @Zyfe3r Hmmm ,That's pretty much all of the steps, And I guess you know that you cannot test push notification in simulator. Are you also using an iPhone or iPad ?

Comment: @Zyfe3r I tried giving answer on stack question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54178448/3278326

Comment: @Zyfe3r Answer includes step by step integration of firebase push notifications.

Comment: @YogeshTandel Oh I figured it out, I didn't add cert for development. I only used for production. Thanks for pointing it out